# Uninstalled Wamp, and need to restore InnoDb tables

Tags: mysql, wamp, innodb

I've uninstalled WAMP from my pc.
The `data` folder of the mySQL is still there and I want to restore the tables and data.
The tables were innoDB

re-installation, didn't work.. any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I moved the files to another server. no luck. -- also as mentioned, installed the wamp again.. no luck as well

Comment: Ah.. there's no error. it simply won't load the innodb tables.

Comment: @RyanVincent INNODB databases are not stored the same as MYISAM tables

Comment: Maybe useful? [manual : This section describes techniques for moving or copying some or all InnoDB tables to a different server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html)

Comment: Did you include ibdata1 in the "move"?

Comment: the uninstall removed it....

Comment: Then you dont have your data to recover.

Comment: @yossi, take an image from the disk and use it for https://launchpad.net/undrop-for-innodb to find the removed tables.